# What CSS rule is used to get rid of the annoying horizontal whitespace when scrolling in mobile apps?

Tags: html, css, scroll, margin

I have verified that this is not any space that any other element has within it... It's just an annoying whitespace that won't let me scroll completely vertically in my web app. Whenever I scroll sideways, it appears... but if I were to let go of the screen, it would just spring back into place!

Anyone know how to fix this? Sorry if the question already exists. I have no idea how to explain this properly... I have already tried  this =>

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I know that this is hard to understand. As an example, if you are using a mobile device, go to https://www.dominos.com/ and try to scroll sideways. You will see it's locked... How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a min-width too, I guess, i use to put something like this instead percent. 
max-width: 100vw;
max-height: 100vh;